# Graphics glitch with NVIDIA GeForce 3060 Ti LHR on GTA V / Witcher 3

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, the-witcher-3, graphics-card

Two months old PC (Windows 10), this glitch started to appear consistently. It's flickering.

I've updated graphics card driver from 49x to 511 to no avail. Tried the lowest graphics settings possible, glitch still there, also tried a clean boot disabling most services and programs at startup.

Don't have a screenshot of the GTA V glitch, but it's somewhat similar, occurs when looking in the sun..

Any ideas how to fix this? Is there a diagnostic tool to see if it's a faulty graphics card? What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Does this kind of graphic error occurs in other game? If so, I'd say it's faulty GPU, but if it doesn't, I would suggest complete wiping your graphics driver by using [DDU](https://www.wagnardsoft.com), and then re-install the driver and see if it consists. If it did, most likely it's faulty GPU... or, problem with driver. I couldn't find any related driver issues though.

Comment: If anyone knows, do LHR cards also limit performance of gaming, video editing and other editing and design works? Or it targets Crypto mining only?

Comment: It was supposed to throttle crypto mining only and about 1.5 months ago they figured out how to unlock LHR cards so they now mine Ethereum at 100% ✌️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They replaced my graphics card under warranty.